# STM32 - Porting/Tailoring Example Files to different Microcontroller - xcubeide

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, smbus, pmbus

How do you convert a project made for one development board for another development board within X-CUBE-IDE.

I am trying to copy a SMBUS example over to a different Development board, so I was wondering what files would needed to be copied inorder for the source code to work for a different board.

Or does anyone have any SMBUS example code for NUCLEO-L496ZG that I could possibly reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is largely identical even if the MCU is wildly different.

Just create a project by using the MCU or the board you have and use the source code for another board as a reference.

The application code will likely require very little changes, if any.

Comment: Yea that's what I'd expect, but doing some SMBUS example has made life a bit difficult with regards to porting.

Comment: Well, what does the example do then and why you want to use the example literally? It is meant to be an example and likely you can do the same by looking at the example, or do what you want by looking at the example.